# How does ComponentScan work?

Tags: java, spring, reflection, annotations, component-scan

`@ComponentScan` will give you a list of all the classes with the `@Component` annotation in a package (or `@Service`/`@Repository`). To do this I imagine they use reflection to enumerate all the classes in a package and find the ones with that annotation.

However according to [other StackOverflow answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520328/can-you-find-all-classes-in-a-package-using-reflection) you can not reliably enumerate all the classes in a package due to how the `ClassLoader`works. So how does `@ComponentScan` seemingly manage to accomplish this?

Comment: With the help of [ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.html)

Comment: The above class has a method `findCandidateComponents` accepting `basePackage` as an input argument and then `ResourcePatternResolver` instance reads all the classpath files with `.class` suffix. Hope this helps!

Comment: @harshavmb, if you turn your comment into an answer, I'll upvote it.

Comment: @NoelYap, so nice of you! I feel it's too late to put it as an answer that I almost forgot Java & Spring. Sorry to disappoint!

Answer (score 10):

`@ComponentScan` works differently. Workflow is put shortly this:

- Find all .class files in same folder and all subfolders
- Read .class file and wrap it into `Resource` object
- Check if class has annotations that will make it good candidate
- If class is good candidate, create bean from it.

Classes from Spring source code to look:

- `ComponentScanAnnotationParser`
- `AnnotationConfigUtils`
- `ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner`
- `BeanDefinitionReaderUtils`
- `DefaultListableBeanFactory`